# Hibernate TABLE_PER_CLASS with @MappedSuperclass won't create UNION query

Tags: hibernate, annotations, union, mappedsuperclass, table-per-class

I am trying to create a series of objects that all are stored in separate tables, but that there is a set of fields in common on all these tables.  I want Hibernate to do a UNION of all these tables, but NOT INCLUDE the superclass as a table.

When I annotate the superclass with just:
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)

...hibernate will run (n) queries separately for the (n) subtypes of the superclass.

When I remove @MappedSuperclass and instead put @Entity on the super class, Hibernate WILL do the fancy UNION query, but includes the superclass as a table in the UNION (there is no table for the superclass).

How do I get it to UNION together all the subclasses (not separate queries) without making the parent class an @Entity (because it's not an entity, there's no table for it)?

Answer (score 7):

I found that marking the parent class as "abstract" did the trick, Hibernate no longer included it in the UNION and *did* UNION together all the sub-classes.